# Two divs with inline-block style not aligned

Tags: html, css

I have two `div` tags and only one has `input` tag; why output is in this way?

```css
div.logo, div.form { 
  display: inline-block;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px dotted;
}
```

```html
<div class="logo">
  <input type="text">
</div>

<div class="form">
</div>
```

### Output:

[image]

Can anyone explain this? Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ag487L5m/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By default, `inline` and `inline-block` elements are set to `vertical-align: baseline`.

Since your `div.logo` has a text input, `div.form` which is now an `inline-block` element, aligns itself on the baseline of the `input`.

Adding `vertical-align: top` to the CSS should fix it.  As in:

```
div.logo, div.form { 
    display: inline-block;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    border: 1px dotted;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

```css
div.logo, div.form { 
    display: inline-block;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    border: 1px dotted;
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

```html
<div class="logo">
  <input type="text">
</div>

<div class="form">

</div>
```

Comment: @ochi adding `vertical-align: top` fixed it.

Comment: @ochi It doesn't have to be fixed if the `div.form` is not going to be empty. However, adding `vertical-align: top` as @j08691 says in their answer will make the tops of both the elements align.

Comment: @tejasvi It's kinda weird because if i remove input tag, it moves back to top aligning itself with 2nd div.

Comment: @Vinay Aggarwal they only *look* aligned at the top because both of them have been given the same height and there is no wriggle room to align in any other way. Change the height of one of the elements and you will find that they will align at the baseline

Answer (score 6):

That's because the vertical alignment of inline elements defaults to baseline. Change it to top:

```
div.logo, div.form { 
  display: inline-block;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px dotted;
  vertical-align:top;
}
```

```css
div.logo, div.form { 
  display: inline-block;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px dotted;
  vertical-align:top;
}
```

```html
<div class="logo">
  <input type="text">
</div>

<div class="form">

</div>
```